# mySQL Switch: How to give "OR" priority or importance in a SELECT statement to get a default row

Tags: mysql

Is there a *simple* way to do a `Switch` in mySQL? Consider this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE
    a=1 OR
    b=2 OR
    c=3 OR
    d=4 OR
    e=5 OR
    f=6
LIMIT 1;
```

This will return a *random* row which matches any part of the OR clause. However, if `a` is the most important column, `b` is the next most important, etc, **how do we alter the query to select only a single row in order of importance?** In other words, we need to first check if `a=1` and return it if true, else check `b=2`, and so on down the list until we find a hit.

The practical use for a query like this is a settings table where we want to see if the user or their administrator, or their organisation has added a custom settings row. If not, we need to select the default settings for that country.

I am thinking possibly of using the `ORDER BY` clause to return the most important row or maybe using a long messy `if/else` to find the most important result but I can't figure out the syntax.

This is very difficult to search so I've added some keywords to the title for SEO.

Comment: I don't see how the order of the `OR` conditions is going to affect whether or not a record ends up in the result set.  Can you clarify your question?

Comment: That is my question! How do we change the query to ensure that the row returned is the one we want?

Comment: Please kindly show us some sample data so that we may better address your question.

Comment: Well I thought `ORDER BY a=1,b=2,c=3...etc LIMIT 1;` would find the first, most important row but it didnt work as expected

Comment: How about this `SELECT * FROM table WHERE IF(a='1',1,IF(b='2',1,IF(c='3',1,IF(d='4',1,IF(e='5',1,IF(f='6',1,0)))))) LIMIT 1`

Comment: Thanks Mobasher, it looks right to me but I tried this one too and it returns the row where `f=6` for some crazy reason.

Comment: May be because no value matched with other conditions for `a,b,c,d,e`. Did you checked your table data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need here is `ORDER BY CASE` clause.

Like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE
a=1 OR
b=2 OR
c=3 OR
d=4 OR
e=5 OR
f=6
ORDER BY CASE WHEN a=1 THEN 0
 WHEN b=2 THEN 1
 WHEN c=3 THEN 2
 ...
 ELSE 3
END
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Thanks Sameer, this one seems to work. Any ideas why `ORDER BY a=1,b=2,c=3...etc LIMIT 1;` doesnt work the same?

Comment: That is specifically because you are giving a _match criteria_ instead of specifying the _sort priority_. SQL Engine wont be able to make out what is the order of priority to sort the result with `a=1,b=2,c=3` as all of them would match on the same priority level.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CASE`, though this is getting ugly soon. It would be better to have your data normalized so you could query it better.

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE
  CASE WHEN a = 1
    THEN a = 1
  ELSE
    CASE WHEN b = 2
      THEN b = 2
    ELSE
      CASE WHEN c = 3
        THEN c = 3
      END END END
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: I tried this and it seems to work backwards? The result I'm getting is the equivalent of `f=6`. Bizarre!

Comment: No, that's not possible if you have continued the query correctly